# How To Disable a Field From Response based on Environment

Tags: java, spring, rest, jackson, spring-profiles

Context:
A Spring REST Web Service where is sends a response with POJO (example: Output.java)
Now, Output.java contains 2 fields -

```
@JsonProperty("One")
private String one;
@JsonProperty("Two")
private String two;
```

So in the response I get both these field.

Question:
How can I disable the field attribute "two" from coming in the response in my PROD environment ?

Comment: There is no any annotation or declaration that prevent properties from serialization on basis of environment. You can add `@JsonIgnore` annotation when you deployed your code to PROD.

Answer (score 0):

You can define custom JsonSerializer for the class and check whether it's PROD in the serializer and skip the field. See an example [here](http://www.davismol.net/2015/06/05/jackson-using-jsonserialize-or-jsondeserialize-annotation-to-register-a-custom-serializer-or-deserializer/)

Answer (score -1):

Declare your Output.java with `JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL`

```
@JsonSerialize(
include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
public class Output {

}
```

If you don't populate property "two" in Output.java, then this property wont appear in your final rest response.

Comment: I need to populate the field anyways for logging. So cant give it to NULL only for PROD.

Comment: Use @JsonIgnore  annotation on private field two.

Comment: When using @JsonIgnore, it gets ignored for DEV environment as well. I just want it to be ignored for PROD alone.

Comment: As StanislavL said, use JSonSerializer or use @JsonFilter